My C# Dictionary only has Null values in it
I am creating a C# Dictionary within Unity to house the states of my Finite State Machine, as listed below.
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AmalgamCentralAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float stunHealth;

    public bool playerInSight;

    public Transform interuptedEvent;

    public GameObject playerTracker;

    public Transform[] leavingAreas;

    private int tensionMeter;

    public AmalgamFSM FSMLogic;

    private void Start()
    {
        interuptedEvent = null;
        FSMLogic = GetComponent<AmalgamFSM>();
        Dictionary<Type, EmptyState> states = new Dictionary<Type, EmptyState>
        {
            {typeof(RoamingState), new RoamingState() },
            {typeof(IdleState), new IdleState() },
            {typeof(StalkingState), new StalkingState() },
            {typeof(HuntingState), new HuntingState() },
            {typeof(HauntingState), new HauntingState() },
            {typeof(LeavingState), new LeavingState() }
        };
        Debug.Log(states);
        FSMLogic.GrabAllStates(states);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        trackPlayerVisability();
    }

    private void trackPlayerVisability()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, playerTracker.transform.position, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            if(hit.transform.tag == "Player")
            {
                playerInSight = true;
            }
            else
            {
                playerInSight = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

Unfortunately the only valuables of the dictionary afterwards only contain Null values. Rather than the states. All the states are child classes of the EmptyState, and all FSMLogic.GrabAllStates does is copy the contents to another script.

states is only valid inside your private method Start().  Where are you checking states and finding it contains null values?

@jdweng I've ran it again with states as a global variable to get the same result. I'm attempting to grab the first value using states.Values.first(), and also attempting the same once its copied over to FSMLogic.GrabAllStates();

Try : states.Values.ToList();  See if any values are not null.

@jdweng It's as a global variable now, but all im getting is an empty list now; "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EmptyState]"

The list is the values and you do not see the keys with states.Values.ToList().  The length of the list is the number of keys you added.  Empty State is a base class with your states like IdelState() are the inherited class.  The empty list is not empty since the length is not zero.  You just can't see the contents because it is private.
